# ag-grid enterprise bundle size

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid but came to know about it's huge bundle size which makes it impossible to add it into the website due to the obvious concerns being raised about increase in bundle size.

I have tried the approach to use modules @ag-grid-community/core which again is 1.88mb in bundle size.

Is there any other approach to decrease the bundle size further and exclude different modules?

Is it the similar case with ag-grid-enterprise? I can see if I include it without license it download ag-grid-community/core module too which again defeat the purpose.

[image]

Comment: Hey - have you found out any workaround or solution for this problem?

Comment: No solution yet even after talking to team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that the majority of the code is in the @ag-grid-community/core package and so is the largest part of AG Grid. This code is shared by the enterprise featurs.

Using the grid feature modules, as described in the [docs](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/modules/) you will be able to just add the enterprise features that you require. As such you may find that the bundle size does not increase that much when moving to Enterprise

I have written the following [article](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/) that walks
through this.